# Jest - How to give describe block access to variables assigned in beforeAll?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I would like my describe block to have access to variables assigned inside the beforeAll function.

For example:

```
let variable_1;
let variable_2;


beforeAll(async () => {
  variable_1 = "hello";
  variable_2 = await getVariable_2();
});

describe('Database Testing', () => {

  console.log(variable_1); // why is this undefined?
  console.log(variable_2); // why is this undefined?

  test(`Testing`, async () => {

    expect('hi').toEqual('hi');

  })
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is `undefined` because `beforeAll` invoke only for tests, not for `describe`,

provide `console log` to test and check results

Comment: This is not possible. you better define the variable on background if you want them to be accessible in describe block

Answer (score 0):

per @Kordrad comment, you need your beforeAll within a describe block

let variable_1;
let variable_2;

```
describe('Database Testing', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    variable_1 = "hello";
    variable_2 = await getVariable_2();
  });


  test(`Testing`, async () => {

    expect('hi').toEqual('hi');

  })
});
```